# Does app tracking transparancy popup give third party cookie access in webview?

Tags: ios, webview, wkwebview, scorm, third-party-cookies

Does the new app tracking transparency popup give access to third party cookies in the webview?

We're trying to show Scorm files in an iframe in the webview. This requires access to third party cookies which is blocked by default. In the iOS versions <14.5, we needed to go to app settings and enable Cross-app tracking toggle to enable third party cookies. There was no way to show a popup for this in the app directly.

Comment: App tracking transparency only controls access to the IDFA. It does not affect the prevent cross site tracking setting for safari.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many reasons that SCORM providers often choose to display the launched SCORM content as a new window instead of an iframe. The new window also allows for better tracking of session-end timings. However I find that that new window launching will come with its own set of problems.

There have been numerous changes in Safari (and other browsers) [regarding cookies and iframe.](https://webkit.org/blog/8311/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-0/)

The basics of what is changing is there is now a 'SameSite' cookie policy, where `Only cookies set as SameSite=None; Secure will be available in third-party contexts, provided they are being accessed from secure connections.`

In Safari, the third-party frame will have to request access to the [storage API](https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/) before the cookie will be accessible.

[Cookie Status](https://www.cookiestatus.com/) is an excellent resource to track how third party cookies work in the different browsers and what you should change to make it work.